# OneSignal - Swift - Receiving push notification in different languages

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, onesignal, nslocalizedstring

I am using the sdk from OneSignal. Let's assume, I have following use case:

User A use my app in German language. He triggers an action within the app e. g. a like on an image of User B. User B gets a push notification about the like. But User B uses the app in English language. How can I achieve that?

I mean, I can send the notification message in a particular language but if User B decides to change the language of the mobile device to Turkish, then I have to be flexibel.

Is there any way, I can access the incoming push notification on the target device?

Currently, my code for sending the notification from the source device looks like this:

```
 public func notifyAboutSubscription(userObject:User, receiverArray:[String]) {
       var receiverArray = removeChallengeCreatorTokenFromArray(receiverArray: receiverArray)
        notificationTypeService.clearReceiverListForNotificationType(completionHandler: { (clearedReceiverArray) in
            receiverArray = clearedReceiverArray

            let source = self.determineUserType(userObject: userObject)
            // actual message is source + FOLLOW_MESSAGE
            OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": source
                + FOLLOW_MESSAGE], "include_player_ids": receiverArray])
        }, receiverList: receiverArray, notificationType: NotificationType.follow)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I just found out the solution. Here is the modified code from above:

```
public func notifyAboutSubscription(userObject:User, receiverArray:[String]) {
    var receiverArray = removeChallengeCreatorTokenFromArray(receiverArray: receiverArray)


    notificationTypeService.clearReceiverListForNotificationType(completionHandler: { (clearedReceiverArray) in
        receiverArray = clearedReceiverArray

        let source = self.determineUserType(userObject: userObject)
        OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": source +
            " started following you", "de": source + " folgt dir jetzt", "tr": source + " seni takip ediyor"], "include_player_ids": receiverArray])
    }, receiverList: receiverArray, notificationType: NotificationType.follow)
}
```

You basically add for each language, the respective key. Depending on the device language, the correct message is shown.